# How to force the RESTkit mapping to always update response NSManagedObject without a unique ID in JSON body

Tags: json, core-data, restkit

I do not have any specific id available in the response JSON body (I can not change the body). That is why I can not use

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:....
mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"specificId"];
```

Is it possible to configure the mapping in such a way that there is no new NSManagedObject created but always the previous one is updated, if such object exists?

I would like to fetch data for ui update from a single response object (of specific class). Yes I can delete the previous instance of the response before the new one is received but the approach required in this question is cleaner and I do not need to keep the reference/id to the response entity.

I am reading the [documentation for RKManagedObjectRequestOperation](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html) but it is not clear whether this approach is supported by Restkit.

Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a hack that is not acceptable but it works: I am using a special attribute in each special "singleton" NSManagedObject's subclass: e.g. *unique* which I use for the identification on the class level:

In RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource there is the condition modified to allow passing entities with the special *unique* attribute:

```
// If we have found the entity identification attributes, try to find an existing instance to update
if ([entityIdentifierAttributes count] || [self.managedObjectCache isUniqueEntityClass:entity])...
```

In *RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache* and in *RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache* there is the new method defined:

```
- (BOOL) isUniqueEntityClass:(NSEntityDescription*)entity {

    __block BOOL isUniqueEntityClass = NO;

    [[[entity attributesByName] allKeys] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        isUniqueEntityClass = [obj isEqualToString:@"unique"];
        if(isUniqueEntityClass) {
            *stop = YES;
            return;
        }
    }];

    return isUniqueEntityClass;
}
```

In the method

```
- (NSSet *)managedObjectsWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity
                    attributeValues:(NSDictionary *)attributeValues
             inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext...
```

*isUniqueEntityClass* decides if we should use predicate based on *attributeValues* to fetch  the entity or directly fetch the entity without the predicate.